# A curious network situation

Tags: networking, xubuntu, samba

I have a home network that is windows based, meaning all of the PCs on this network are running windows OSes (from WinXP to Windows 10). I run Xubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop (dual boot w win 8.1). The 'curious situation' is that one particular PC needs to be running in order for my Xubuntu to see the network. If that PC is not active (turned off), Xubuntu does not see any of the computers in my network. However, once that PC is turned back on and made available to the network again, Xubuntu sees and can access all of the network except my Windows 10 desktop. This particular PC (that makes network available to xubuntu) is a simple file server (as are all of the PCs except the laptop and the Windows 10 desktop).
   My question is; is this more common or do I have a 'weird' situation? I have been attempting to configure samba so that the network is always available (to no avail). And again, once that PC is available on the network,the entire 'file server set' is available to Xubuntu.
   I find it puzzling that all shares are accessible (copy, paste, etc). But once that certain PC is turned off, nothing (shares not even visible, in fact, the workgroup and computers not visible).
   Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the design of Windows Server Message Block (SMB) protocol and NetBIOS. A machine is asked to be the goto directory for all other computers on the network. This is suppose to be passed on to another computer if the current one is down. But it rarely turns out that way. For me I keep a Linux based SAMBA server that always forces itself to be the WINs server and I get consistent results on the Windows and Linux computers.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This does help me in that I have thought my WIN10 desktop was the goto pc you describe. However, that PC does not have 'WakeonLAN' and when I 1st installed Xubuntu 16.04 LTS, perhaps samba established the other PC as the goto due to the WIN10 desktop being 'asleep'.